# Linq-to-Sql Group by inner join select min

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I am trying to convert this query into linq to sql preferably using VB.NET.  If you only know C# I can most likely convert it.

```
select
    ha.HouseholdID_in,
    MIN(t.TradeDate_dt) AS FirstTradeDate_dt
from dbo.ivwHouseholdAccounts ha
    inner join dbo.trans t
        on ha.accountid_in = t.accountid_in
group by ha.HouseholdID_in
```

Can anyone give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example of what it should look like in C#. Hope it helps.

```
using (var context = new ExamenEnLigneDataContext())
{
    Dictionary<int, DateTime> lastDates = 
           (from ha in context.ivwHouseholdAccounts
           join t in context.trans
           on ha.accountid_in equals t.accountid_in
           group ha by new {ha.HouseholdID_in} into grp
           select new KeyValuePair<int,DateTime>(
               grp.Key.HouseholdID_in,
               grp.Min(t => t.TradeDate_dt)
           ).ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value);
}
```